# Not being able to display values from the Redux Store even though the store is being updated successfully

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is probably a very simple question. I am creating an app where I can up vote or down vote on a certain post. All of the posts are fetched in a back end server. to up vote or downvote I just send a post request with a specific ID, then I replace the current object with the new object with the new vote value.

But everything is working perfectly. I have a middleware that logs my store state and the updated data seems to be ok. But the component doesn't show the right values.

I tried using mapStateToProps to get the property I want and display it but it doesn't work.

I have 2 components: Posts and Post.

inside the Post component I have this code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { dispatch } = this.props

    dispatch(getAllPosts());
}
```

This populates my redux.

Then I use:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
    posts: state.posts
   }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Posts);
```

and finally I create every post inside the render():

```
render() {
    const { posts } = this.props;

    return (
     <div>
        {
          posts !== undefined && (
            posts.map(post => (
              console.log('sending this post: ', post),
              <Post post={post}></Post>
            ))
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The post then receives the post prop and renders each post:

```
 render() {
    const { post } = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="postArea">
            <i className="far fa-trash-alt iconTop"></i><i 
className="fas fa-edit iconTop"></i>
            <p style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>{post.body}</p>
            <div className="bottomPost">
            <i className="far fa-thumbs-up iconBottom" onClick={this.handleLike} name="upVote"></i><i onClick={this.handleLike} name="downVote" className="far fa-thumbs-down iconBottom"></i>{post.voteScore}
            <span className="commentsIndicator"> {post.commentCount} Comments     </span>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

and this is the function triggered whenever I click the like or dislike button:

```
handleLike = (e) => {

    const { id } = this.state
    const { handleLikeThunk } = this.props;

    if(e.target.getAttribute('name') === 'upVote'){
      handleLikeThunk(id, 'upVote');

    }
    if(e.target.getAttribute('name') === 'downVote'){
      handleLikeThunk(id, 'downVote');

    }

  }
```

However, when I click on either button. Nothing happens (even though the logger middleware shows the store has updated) and when I reload the page, the like count shows the right number. It just doesn't show it on the fly, while I am clicking it.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've had this exact same problem in the past when working with FontAwesome and React. Wrap your icon in a span with a key of Math.Random() like this:

```
<span key={Math.random()}>
    <i className="far fa-thumbs-up iconBottom" onClick={this.handleLike} name="upVote"></i>
</span>
```

Why? Because svgs, which what Font Awesome uses for their icons don't auto re-render on the virtual DOM as one would typically expect. Having the span with that key forces them to do so.

Comment: Using math random as a key is a terrible idea, because React will not update the current component, instead, because the key will be totally different, it will create a brand new one on every rerender. This affects performance A LOT.

Comment: it didnt work. The problem is that the "like count" is not wrapped inside the <i>. It's just there